# Getting 'undefined method' error or 'no such file to load error' trying to use validates_timeliness gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I'm trying to use the validates_timeliness gem and followed the install instructions in the documentation: https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness

gem 'validates_timeliness', '3.0.2'
bundle install
rails generate validates_timeliness:install

I was then able to successfully add rspec tests and get them to pass using the validates_datetime feature from the gem

However, when I go to my new view in a browser, I get the error:

undefined method 'validates_datetime' for #

I also tried adding require 'validates_timeliness' at the top of the model file and then later at the top of the controller file.  In those cases I get the error: 'no such file to load -- validates_timeliness

Any help would be much appreciated, have been trying to do extensive googling.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in [the instructions](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness#installation), it must be installed as both a plugin and a gem. When installed as a gem alone, seems to work fine with RSpec, but not in the browser.

## How I fixed:

So anyone else that runs into this problem may also try running this code from **master** to install as plugin:

```
rails plugin install git://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness.git
```

[adzap/validates_timeliness#installation](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness#installation)